# How to fetch the pid and kill it using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i have to find a processid for a specific jar file and kill it using the same batch file.

```
C:\Users\k9>ps -ef|grep java
  10892   5648  0   Mar 08 con  0:02 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java"  com.mkwebappserver.MainClass -app CATMkWebAppServerConsole\apps_list.html -autobui
  13060   7828  0 09:42:28 con 49:05 java  -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -Djava.util.logging.config.file=..\config\log.properties -classpath "../extlib/*";..\extlib\mysql-connector-
```

here i want to find pid of config\log.properties file and kill it using the batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way to detect a pid by its command line (where your jar should be included) is with wmic. To process the `wmic` result and assign it to a variable you'll need `FOR /F` :

```
@echo off

for /f  "useback tokens=* delims=" %%# in (
    `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%my_jar.jar%%' and not CommandLine like '%%wmic%%' " get  ProcessId /Format:Value`
) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%#") do set "%%a"
)

echo %processId%

echo taskkill /pid %processId% /f
```

Where you should change `'%%my_jar.jar%%'` with your jar name.To kill the process you'll have to delete the `echo` word in the last line. It is echoed in order to check if the correct process id is handled.

For more info:

[***WMIC***](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

[***FOR /F***](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

[***WQL***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx)

[***TASKKILL***](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I "find" and kill Adobe Acrobat

```
::Close acrobat and any opened PDF
taskkill /im acrobat.exe /t /f 
timeout 2

/im for imagename, or program you're targeting
/t terminates the specified process and any child process which were started by it
/f Forcefully terminate the process
```

Comment: Oh thank you, the /t was the flag I was looking for